# In Fortran, what is the most memory conservative way to have an instance variable that is seldom initialized?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to design an object that has an instance variable of type `REAL` that may or may not contain a value, that is, it may be undefined in some instances.

```
TYPE :: object
    REAL :: result_of_some_calculation
END TYPE object
```

Since this instance variable may not always be defined, I wonder if there is a prudent way to avoid consuming memory for this instance variable until it is initialized. That is, I could do the following:

```
TYPE :: object
    REAL, POINTER :: result_of_some_calculation => NULL()
    CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: get_calculation_result
END TYPE

SUBROUTINE get_calculation_result(self)
   IMPLICIT NONE
   CLASS(object) :: self
   REAL, TARGET :: result
   result = some_function()
   self%result_of_some_calculation => result
END SUBROUTINE get_calculation_result
```

So, would the pointer when its nullified use less memory than when it points to a REAL?

I understand that in this case, I have the memory cost of the `REAL` and the memory cost of the `POINTER`, but I'm hoping that in the more common case when this pointer is always left nullified, I use less memory than if I used a `REAL` in my derived data type and left this `REAL` undefined.

Alternatively, I could create an allocatable array of one element:

```
    TYPE :: object
        REAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: result_of_some_calculation
        CONTAINS
        PROCEDURE :: get_calculation_result
    END TYPE

    SUBROUTINE get_calculation_result(self)
       IMPLICIT NONE
       CLASS(object) :: self
       REAL, TARGET :: result

       result = some_function()
       ALLOCATE(self%result_of_some_calculation(1))
       self%result_of_some_calculation(1) = result
    END SUBROUTINE get_calculation_result
```

Would this use less memory?

In short, my question is, what are the memory costs of a nullified pointer, versus an unallocated array, versus a real (which I know to be 4 bytes lets say)?

Comment: [Not an answer, as it isn't definitive and we're very much in the realm of implemenation-specific.] One would expect the pointer/allocatable array to take at least the 32 bits of your real, but even if there were savings the extra complexity/non-intuitiveness compared with a real (perhaps with a guard-NaN) must surely not be worth it?  Do you have a situation in mind where it is important, rather than being a curiosity (which is no bad thing, of course)?

Comment: I do have a situation in that this object will be created an enormous number of times and memory savings would be worthwhile but if memory costs cannot be mitigated then so be it. I'll look for memory savings elsewhere.

Comment: If lots of them, then it certainly is worth considering - it may be worth stressing this in the question?  Further, do you always need the large number of `type(object)`s to exist even when there is no defined result?

Answer (score 2):

This is implementation specific, but a pointer to a non-polymorphic **scalar** object (or an allocatable for such an object) is typically implemented by a machine level pointer.  If your code is compiled for and running on a platform with 32 bit (4 byte) machine level pointers, then this approach results in no memory saving for an unused object, and double the memory consumption when the object is in use, on top of any performance impacts of the indirect reference (and the aliasing potential for the pointer case).

If you are compiling for and running on a platform with 64 bit pointers, the machine level pointer is twice the size of the data being pointed at.

If you are dealing with polymorphic objects, there typically is another machine level pointer involved, to describe the dynamic type of the object being pointed at/allocated.

Implementations may have other fields in the descriptor for a scalar object.

Even more implementation specific, but a pointer to or allocatable for a non-polymorphic **array** object will require, in addition to the machine level pointer to the actual data, information about the bounds (or bound and extent) of the object - say 12 bytes minimum on a 32 bit platform for a rank one array.  In the case of a pointer you also need to store a stride - another four bytes. Implementations typically will have additional fields for various flags and other conveniences and often use the same data structure for pointers and allocatable objects (and also assumed shape objects and polymorphic and non-polymorphic objects).  As an example, one 32 bit platform I am familiar with has a 36 byte descriptor for a rank one array - nine times the storage of the fundamentally scalar thing that the descriptor might be pointing at in your use case.  Eighteen times if you are on a 64 bit platform.

These are not the memory savings you are looking for.

(Note that associating a pointer with a non-saved local object of a procedure is pointless - the pointer becomes undefined when the procedure terminates.)